# Formatting an Excel text field from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a string like "Saturday, November 28, 2015 11:59:59 PM GMT-5" in an Excel spreadsheet and would like to remove the Day of the week and Time Zone before importing it to Access using VBA. I tried :

ExcelWorksheet.Cells(1 + counter, nIdCol) = left((ExcelWorksheet.Cells(1 + counter, nIdCol)), Find(" GMT", ExcelWorksheet.Cells(1 + counter, nIdCol) - 1)) "

but found that "Find" is not an Access function.

Any idea to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in Excel, before importing to Access with VBA, you can use this formula to trim them.  Note: I'm assuming that each of your strings will have "GMT" at the end to denote the time zone, and will have a `,` after the day of the week.

If `Saturday, November 28, 2015 11:59:59 PM GMT-5` is in A1, use this formula in B1:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(", ",A1)+1,SEARCH("GMT",A1)-SEARCH(", ",A1)-2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Instr() function. Replace Find("GMT") with

```
Instr(string:=ExcelWorksheet.Cells(1 + counter, nIdCol).Value, substring:="GMT") - 1
```

More on the Instr() function: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php